# TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to scalar index while converting dataframe "to_datetime"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing but I'm getting this typeError during the 'to_datetime' conversion for the date column which is formatted as 'object.' I have tried different variations of this code but I still get the same error.  I'm using the PyCharm IDE.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data/myData.csv')
df.columns = [['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']]
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m%d%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')

# print(df.dtypes)
print(df.head())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is problem is convert nested list to columns get one level `MultiIndex`.

So for prevent it use:

```
df.columns = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
```

Or skip first row in file (original header) and set new header by `names` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/myData.csv', 
                 skiprows=1,
                 names=['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume'])
```

Comment: Thanks.  The main problem was the double brackets and I didn't have the current formatting correct.  I was following a video and they had double brackets.  Not sure how he got it done with the double brackets, but my code works now.  Thanks jez!